# Receiving Content-Length:0 in header with Response code 200 for GET Response from Java client

Tags: java, rest, http

When I am trying to hit a `REST API URL` **http:URL?param-name=param-value**
for downloading a `JSON` file from `Java` client, I am receiving the response body as empty with `Content-Length:0` in header and with status code as 200.

I used `RestTemplate/HttpURLConnection/Apache HttpClient` to get the file content.. But no Luck

However, file is downloadable from browser or any other `REST` client like `SOAP` or from command line like `wget` or `curl` (I guess because output mime type is automatically detected by all these tools).

## Request and Response headers when request fired from Chrome ARC client

### Request

> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko)  Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36
>
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
>
> Accept: application/octet-stream
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
>
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
>
> Cookie:
>   JSESSIONID=49LkWLLJMdNWhHRzh7FclGGSXvV2NKpbK0PYvCFp3vGFc2mwfpGh!-1680860256

### Response

> Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
>
> Date: Wed, 24 Feb 2016 05:05:20 GMT
>
> Pragma: no-cache
>
> Content-Length: 342950
>
> Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>
> Expires: 0
>
> Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=DevicePrices.json
>
> X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
>
> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>
> X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2
>
> X-Frame-Options: DENY

## Request and Response from java client

### Request Headers

> Header-->Accept-charset-->UTF-8
>
> Header-->Accept-->application/octet-stream
>
> Header-->Accept-Encoding-->gzip,deflate,sdch
>
> Header-->Content-Type-->text/plain;charset=utf-8
>
> Header-->Accept-Language-->en-US,en;q=0.8

### Response Headers

> Header-->Cache-Control-->no-cache, no-store, max-age=0,
>   must-revalidate
>
> Header-->Date-->Wed, 24 Feb 2016 04:32:39 GMT
>
> Header-->Pragma-->no-cache
>
> Header-->Content-Length-->0
>
> Header-->Content-Type-->application/octet-stream
>
> Header-->Expires-->0
>
> Header-->Content-Disposition-->attachment; filename=DevicePrices.json
>
> Header-->X-XSS-Protection-->1; mode=block
>
> Header-->X-Content-Type-Options-->nosniff
>
> Header-->X-Powered-By-->Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2
>
> Header-->X-Frame-Options-->DENY

I tried to mock the request headers but still the same issue that no content body received. I am stuck with this since long.

What might be the reasons for this behavior? 
Please suggest me the ways to retrieve the file content.

Adding the code snippet using Apache HttpClient:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get=new HttpGet(url);
get.setHeader("Accept-charset", "UTF-8");
get.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
get.setHeader("Accept","*/*");
get.setHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip,deflate,sdch");
get.setHeader("Content-Type","text/plain;charset=utf-8");
get.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
HttpResponse resp=client.execute(get);
System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity()));
```

If I use get.setHeader("Accept","application/json"), server responding in 406-Non Acceptable error.

Comment: Do you normally have to login to get this resource?  You have no JSESSIONID in your java request.  Or perhaps the server has a bug when no user-agent header is provided.  Try sending one.

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you request an `application/octet-stream` when you want an `application/json`?

Comment: the request / response values are not terribly informative.  It seems that the code that implemented the get returned zero results and thus the zero length body.

Comment: @WW- No login required . I tried providing a JSESSIONID but same issue.

Comment: @DwB- The same code returning results for another GET API . I tried many ways as I said using RestTemplate/HttpURLConnection/Apache HttpClient  trying with different request headers. But same issue

Comment: My issue is solved. The API which I am calling takes a token from another API.The content is ready only after 5 min delay with that token .That's why , content is empty with status 200 from java client. When I am using other clients , I was using an old token for which content was ready.